# How can I avoid Array-callback-return error in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, eslint, higher-order-functions

I want to filter through a list of items and display the items according to my filtered term.

My list of items

```js
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
        { name: 'Arton Senna', tel: '9900000000' },
        { name: 'Ada Lovelace', tel: '39-44-5323523' },
        { name: 'Dan Abramov', tel: '12-43-234345' },
        { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', tel: '39-23-6423122' }
    ])
```

I have a input element that is a search field

```html
    <div>
        <label htmlFor='filter'>Filter phonebook with</label>
        <input type='text' name='filter_contacts' id='filter' onChange={filterText} />
    </div>
```

The search field has an onchange handler

```js
const filterText = (event) => {
        return setFilter(event.target.value)
    }
```

I am rendering the list items using `.map` helper method

```js
    <ul>
       {persons.map(person => <li key={person.tel}>{person.name} {person.tel}</li>)}
    </ul>
```

My state objects are as follows

```js
// persons
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
        { name: 'Arton Senna', tel: '9900000000' },
        { name: 'Ada Lovelace', tel: '39-44-5323523' },
        { name: 'Dan Abramov', tel: '12-43-234345' },
        { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', tel: '39-23-6423122' }
    ])
// serachField
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')
```

I want the ability to render my list according to what I type in my `<input/>` element for search, so I did the following

```js
     <ul>
       {persons
           .filter(person => {
               if (filter === '') {
                  return person
               } else if (person.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())) {
                  return person
               }})
            .map(person => <li key={person.tel}>{person.name} {person.tel}</li>)}
     </ul>
```

After doing this, `eslint` gives me the following warning message 
**`Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function.eslintarray-callback-return`**

**Please help me understand this issue and how can I ...**

- **Use another approach here**, to do what I want with filtering and rendering my list
- **What is the problem with the way I'm doing it?** (the code still works properly, but that warning message is annoying me)
- What is **a succinct way** to do the same task

`@Quentin` I did the following refactor

```js
                    {
                        filter
                            // truthy 
                            ? persons.filter(person => person.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())).map(person => <li key={person.tel}>{person.name} {person.tel}</li>)
                            // falsy 
                            : persons.map(person => <li key={person.tel}>{person.name} {person.tel}</li>)
                    }
```

Comment: The `filter` callback should return a boolean value, not a person-or-undefined.

Comment: Regarding the refactoring, don't repeat the `map` call. Write `(filter ? persons.filter(…) : persons).map(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi didnt think about that, thats awesome, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the problem with the way I'm doing it?

ESLint wants you to explicitly return something: always.

If the code gets to the end of the function, it *implicitly* returns `undefined`. ESlint expects you to be explicit.

```
person => {
  if (filter === '') {
    return person
  } else if (person.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())) {
    return person
  }
  return false; // Explicit
}
```

> What is a succinct way to do the same task

```
person => (filter === '' || person.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()).toLowerCase())
```

… should do the trick.

Comment: `return person` is still wrong. A proper typechecker would complain there as well.

Comment: Im adding an edit to my code, I used a ternary operator and it worked, a follow up question so using the if/else version is okay as long as i use explicit return? I am editing my post, please take a look at my refactor, thank you for you solution